# Подтвердить ввод данных в окне импортированом

Tags: python, qt, pycharm, pyside

Есть окно:

```
class MainWnd(QMainWindow, mainGui.Ui_RecistMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainWnd, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setupUi(self) 
            self.baseline_btn.clicked.connect(self.baseline_clicked)
        def baseline_clicked(self):
            dialogbs = BaseLine(self.id_label.text())
            dialogbs.exec_()
```

в нем вызивается другое окно:

```
class BaseLine(QDialog, baselineGui.Ui_BaseLine):

    def __init__(self, id_value, parent=None):
        super(BaseLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def accept(self):

        class GreaterThan(Exception): pass
        class LessThan(Exception): pass

        try:
            if self.target1_type.isChecked() and int(self.lineEdit.text()) < 15: #ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
                raise GreaterThan, ('Nodal lesion should be >= 15 mm in short axis')
            elif int(self.lineEdit.text()) < 10 and not self.target1_type.isChecked() :
                raise LessThan, ('Non-nodal lesion should be >= 10 mm in long axis')
            else:
                self.buttonBox.Ok.clicked.connect.accept() ### ПРАВКА ЭТОЙ СТРОКИ


        except GreaterThan, e:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, str(e))
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.target1_type.setFocus()
            return

        except LessThan, e:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, str(e))
            self.lineEdit.clear()
            self.target1_type.setFocus()
            return
```

в котором ввод данных является ограниченым(ограничение функцией def accept(self): ).
Оба окна созданы в QtDesigner  и импортятся в основной код.
ограничения на ввод работают, ноно подтверждение(принятие - accept) введенных данных по нажатию кнопки OK не производится. 
До создания функции по ограниченнию на введенные данные высе работало.
в модуле который мы импортируем accept-reject работаел таким образом:

```
class Ui_BaseLine(object):
    def setupUi(self, BaseLine):
        BaseLine.setObjectName("BaseLine")
...

        self.retranslateUi(BaseLine)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("accepted()"), BaseLine.accept)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox, QtCore.SIGNAL("rejected()"), BaseLine.reject)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(BaseLine)
```

не могу сообразить как сделать подтверждение введенных данных в окне BaseLine в функции def accept(self):
собственно нужно исправить эту строку

```
self.buttonBox.Ok.clicked.connect.accept()
```

но я только начал изучать Pyside и пока не могу понять как это сделать.

Comment: Вроде в документации написано, что у [QCheckBox есть сигнал def stateChanged](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QCheckBox) и у [QLineEdit есть сигнал def textChanged](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QLineEdit.html). Может стоит их использовать, вместо этого `self.buttonBox.Ok.clicked.connect.accept()`? Заведите функцию проверки длины в зависимости от параметров и вызывайте ее при срабатывании сигналов.

Answer (score 0):

Решение было на поверхности...

```
QDialog.accept(self)
```